# How to perform shuffle on a list of words?

Tags: r, random, shuffle, sample, permute

I want to do a shuffle on a list of words in R, either using `permute::shuffle/shuffleSet()` or any other function.

Code:

```
require(permute)
a <- c("Ar","Ba","Bl","Bu","Ca")
x <- list(a)
x
shuffleSet(x)
shuffle(x)
```

But when I try this code I get the error

```
shuffleSet : Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer

shuffle : Error in factor(rep(1, n)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

Should `permute::shuffle/shuffleSet()` only be used only for integers? How do I perform a shuffle for the above list? Is there any other function to do this?

Comment: did u try `shuffleSet(as.integer(x))`

Comment: A slight modification `shuffleSet(as.integer(x[[1]]))`

Comment: When i try the code shuffleSet(as.integer(x)) I get the error Error in shuffleSet(as.integer(x)) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'.   And when i try the code shuffleSet(as.integer(x[[1]])) I get the error Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In shuffleSet(as.integer(x[[1]])) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In seq_len(n) : first element used of 'length.out' argument. Does it mean shuffle cant be used with non integers?

Comment: Deterministically, randomly ("sampling") or random-seeded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not use sample?

```
     > a <- c("Ar","Ba","Bl","Bu","Ca")
     > a
     [1] "Ar" "Ba" "Bl" "Bu" "Ca"
     > x <- list(a)
     > x
     [[1]]
     [1] "Ar" "Ba" "Bl" "Bu" "Ca"
     > x[[1]][sample(1:length(a))]
     [1] "Ba" "Bu" "Ar" "Bl" "Ca"
```

Comment: This is even easier if you skip converting to a list: `sample(a,length(a),replace=FALSE)`

Comment: The codes with sample work fine. Thank you :)

Comment: @RVRLibra: random-sampling without `set.seed()` is irreproducible and is an absolute no-no if this code will ever get anywhere near production.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate the entire shuffle set, rather than a random permutation, you can try the following:

```
require(permute)
a <- c("Ar","Ba","Bl","Bu","Ca")
x <- list(a)
y <- shuffleSet(as.factor(x[[1]]), quietly=TRUE)
y[] <- sapply(y, function(x) a[x])
y <- as.data.frame(y)
> head(y)
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#1 Ar Ba Bl Ca Bu
#2 Ar Ba Bu Bl Ca
#3 Ar Ba Bu Ca Bl
#4 Ar Ba Ca Bl Bu
#5 Ar Ba Ca Bu Bl
#6 Ar Bl Ba Bu Ca
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is still some issue with the integer conversion. I get the following error         Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In shuffleSet(as.integer(x[[1]])) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In seq_len(n) : first element used of 'length.out' argument

Comment: It seems that you did not use the code I posted. I'm not using `as.integer()` but `as.factor()`. With this, I can't confirm your error message. I only get the message `'nperm' >= set of all permutations: complete enumeration.
Set of permutations < 'minperm'. Generating entire set.`, which is not more than just an information.

Comment: @RVRLibra The output described in my previous comment, which is neither a warning nor an error, can be suppressed with the option `quietly=TRUE`. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I am not getting the desired output. I get the erroe message "Error in shuffleSet(as.factor(x[[1]]), quietly = TRUE) : 
  unused argument (quietly = TRUE)" and my outout is "[1] V1
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)" Am not sure what the issue is

Comment: I'm using `permute` version 0.9-0 on R version 3.2.3. Maybe the behavior is different on older versions. In fact, I see that the option `quietly` has been added in the latest release of the package. You might want to update the package with `install.packages("permute")`

Comment: I just updated my package version and it works fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is really a follow-up to the other answers - go upvote both of them, not this one.

If all you want to do is randomly permute a vector of observations, `sample()` from the base R installation works just fine (as shown by @t.f in their answer):

```
a <- c("Ar","Ba","Bl","Bu","Ca")
x <- list(a)
sample(a)
sample(x[[1]])

> sample(a)
[1] "Ca" "Bu" "Ba" "Ar" "Bl"
> sample(x[[1]])
[1] "Bl" "Ba" "Bu" "Ar" "Ca"
```

Note you don't need `sample(1:length(a))` or to use this to index into `x[[1]]`; `sample()` does the right thing if you give it a vector as input, as shown above.

`shuffle()` and `shuffleSet()` were designed as an interface to restricted permutations but they needed to handle complete randomisation as a special case and so if you dig deep enough you'll see that `shuffle` or `shuffleSet` call `shuffleFree` and internally that uses `sample.int()` (for efficiency reasons, but for all intents and purposes this is a call to `sample()` just a bit more explicit about setting all arguments.)

Because these two functions were designed for more general problems, all we need to know is the number of observations to iterate; hence the first argument to both should be the number of observations. If you pass them a *vector*, then as a little bit of sugar I just compute `n` from the size of the object (length for a vector, nrow for a matrix etc).

@RHertel notes that `shuffleSet()` generates, with this example, all the permutations of the set `a`. This is due to heuristics that try to provide better random permutations when the set of permutations is small. A more direct way of generating the set of all permutations is to do it via `allPerms()`:

```
> head(allPerms(seq_along(a)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    5    4
[2,]    1    2    4    3    5
[3,]    1    2    4    5    3
[4,]    1    2    5    3    4
[5,]    1    2    5    4    3
[6,]    1    3    2    4    5
```

Note that `allPerms(a)` won't work because `a` is of class `"character"` and there isn't a `nobs()` method for that (but I'll go fix that in **permute** so it will work in future.)

`shuffle` and `shuffleSet` return permutations of the *indices* of the thing you want to permute, not the permuted elements themselves; in fact they never really know about the actual elements/things you want to permute. Hence why @RHertel uses the `sapply` call to apply the permuted indices to `a`. A quicker way of doing this is to store the permutations and then insert back into this matrix of permutations the elements of `a`, *indexed by the permutation matrix*:

```
perms <- allPerms(seq_along(a)) # store all permutations
perms[] <- a[perms]             # replace elements of perms with shuffled elements of a

> perms <- allPerms(seq_along(a))
> perms[] <- a[perms]
> head(perms)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "Ar" "Ba" "Bl" "Ca" "Bu"
[2,] "Ar" "Ba" "Bu" "Bl" "Ca"
[3,] "Ar" "Ba" "Bu" "Ca" "Bl"
[4,] "Ar" "Ba" "Ca" "Bl" "Bu"
[5,] "Ar" "Ba" "Ca" "Bu" "Bl"
[6,] "Ar" "Bl" "Ba" "Bu" "Ca"
```

The efficiency here is that the replacement is done in a single function call to `<-.[()`, rather than separate calls to `[()`. You need the `[]` on `perms` otherwise you'd overwrite `perms` not replace *in place*.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful post! I decided to ignore your initial recommendation since I think that an upvote is more than well-deserved here.